# Laravel with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5, oci8

I'm trying to connect oracle 10g XE with laravel 5.7
for checking connection I'm using the following code

```
<?php
try {
DB::connection()->getPdo();
print_r('connected');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo '<pre>';
    die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration. error:" . $e );
}
?>
```

I'm facing following error

> Please check your configuration.
>   error:Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception: ORA-00000: normal,
>   successful completion in
>   \laravelOracle\vendor\yajra\laravel-pdo-via-oci8\src\Pdo\Oci8.php:464

following are my .env configuration for Oracle

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=XE
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
DB_CHARSET=AL16UTF16
DB_SERVER_VERSION=10.2
```

Comment: `ORA-00000` does not appear to be an actual error.  Are you certain that your PHP code threw an exception?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm also curious that ora-00000 is not an actual error, and yes PHP code threw an exception. as I described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You´re missing the connection parameter

Write this code on any "get" route of an controller

```
$test = DB::connection('oracle') -> select("Select (2+2)/2 from dual");

dd($test);
```